# How would I go about reducing a fraction?

Tags: c#, math

So I have a little question. I am trying to reduce a fraction in C#. I did some work to check if the user entered a string and have it display a message, I would like to know how to reduce the fraction the user entered and possibly also have my program check to see if the user entered a zero for the denominator and have it display a message saying "Can't divide by zero."

Any help would be appreciated!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FractionApplication
{
class FractionApplicaton
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double numerator;
        double denominator;
        string inputData;
        bool goodData;

        Console.Write("Please enter a numerator: ");
        inputData = Console.ReadLine();
        goodData = double.TryParse(inputData, out numerator);

        if (goodData != true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The numerator entered contains bad data.");
        }

        else
        {

            Console.Write("\nPlease enter a denominator: ");
            inputData = Console.ReadLine();
            goodData = double.TryParse(inputData, out denominator);

            if (goodData != true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The denominator entered contains bad data.");

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The original fraction was: {0}/{1}",numerator,denominator);

            }
        }



    }
}
```

}

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
int temp;
if(numerator<denominator)temp = numerator;
else  temp = denominator;
for(int i=temp/2; i>1; i--){
    if(numerator%i==0 && denominator%1==0){
        //this is a common denominator and you can divide both by i
    }
}
```

We are looking for a common factor for both the numerator and denominator. No common factor can be larger than half the size of the smaller number, so we see which one is smaller and set i to half that value. Then we use % to get the remainder of the numerator/i and the denominator/i.

If both are zero then we have a common factor and since we started at temp/2 and counted down, not 0 counting up, it will be the largest common factor. You can put this anywhere after you ensure that the numerator and denominator are valid.

You might want to make the values ints instead of doubles. You won't have 2.01/3.56 as a fraction right?  I'm not sure that the % operator works with doubles.

Comment: this should have better explanation.

Comment: where should i place this? @Scott

Comment: Sorry.  We are looking for a common factor for both the numerator and denominator.  No common factor can be larger than half the size of the smaller number, so we see which one is smaller and set i to half that value.  Then we use % to get the remainder of the numerator/i and the denominator/i.  If both are zero then we have a common factor and since we started at temp/2, not 0, it will be the largest common factor.   You can put this anywhere after you ensure that the numerator and denominator are valid.  You might want to make the values ints instead of doubles.  you won't have 2.01/3.56

Comment: Please edit your answer to include the explanation, rather than posting it as a comment.